# How can I add custom code to Drupals .htaccess and make sure it will stay there

Tags: 9, .htaccess

For one of my Drupal 9 website I need to add a custom code to the htaccess file to redirect the visitors from one subdomain to another for this I use the following code:

```
#Custom Rewrite Rule
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://new-subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

I put this code directly under the `RewriteEngine on` on line 68.

But I know that updating my Drupal site might overwrite these lines of code. How do I make sure these changes to the .htaccess file are permanent?

Comment: Might be worth explaining how you update your drupal code base. E.g. if you download and copy/paste manually or if you use composer? If it's composer you could look into creating a patch for .htacess which composer runs after an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patching scaffolded files is [documented](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-composer-scaffold#toc_4) precisely.

```
"name": "my/project",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
      "cd docroot && patch -p1 <../patches/htaccess-ssl.patch"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: If you need help creating a patch that is a different question which isn’t Drupal-specific.